# Yii2 - validate password (Hash is invalid error)

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to validate old user password, in order for him to able to change password, but at the moment I am getting **Hash is invalid** error.

This is validation rule:

```
['password_old', function($attribute){
                if(!$this->validatePassword($this->{$attribute}))
                    $this->addError($attribute, 'Please Enter Your Old Password');
            }],
```

**validatePassword** method:

```
    public function validatePassword($password){
            return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->salt . $password, $this->password);
        }
```

Form used for changing the password:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(
            [
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'action'               => 'user/changepassword',
                'id'                   => 'changePassword'
            ]
        );


    echo $form->field($model, 'password_old')->passwordInput( ['autocomplete' => 'off'] );
    echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['autocomplete' => 'off'])->label('New Password');
    echo $form->field($model, 'password_confirm')->passwordInput(['autocomplete' => 'off']);
```

Comment: Why $this->salt? Do you add another salt on purpose? Hash password is already salted. And I'm not 100% sure but it looks like you compare $this->salt . $password with $this->password and $this->password is raw new password from form input but you should compare it with old password hash.

Comment: i have this error in change pass for user. how to fix this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218661/after-make-or-change-password-user-dont-login-in-yii2

Answer (score 2):

Another reason the **Hash is invalid error** occurs if when you pass a null as the `$hash` to the `Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword` method.

I suggest you do a check like this in your code

```
public function validatePassword($password){
        if(is_null($this->password)) 
            return false;
        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->salt . $password, $this->password);
    }
```

Comment: what salt here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm solved the problem, when change value of password column in DB from varchar(128) to varchar(255) and registerd again.

Comment: my field is text but i have problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218661/after-make-or-change-password-user-dont-login-in-yii2

Answer (score 0):

**"Hash is invalid error"** because your password is not correct format.

Why?

- When you call validatePassword in a validate rule, `$this->password` is not password stored in database, It is new password - recently submit from your form. To solve problems, you can refer `LoginForm` class in `yii2-basic-app` or `yii-advanced-app`.

Suggestions:

- **"Salt"** is not necessary because it was included automatically in function `\Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash` (PHP 5>= 5.5.0 `password_hash`)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and **resolved**.

The reason is that I used to use the sha1 algorithm before, and after converting it to [bcrypt](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html) (`Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash`), I encountered this problem.

My previous password was created with the sha1 algorithm and was in the database.
When I changed the code to the new algorithm and wanted to login, I was wrong.

If you reset the previous password with the new algorithm, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when the compared password in the database cannot be a hash value!
I get this error when the field value

"  $2y$13$TvlDZ5RgBL7Cr1LR9JovfOVEyMwpD6x1dy9sYlngzUIKeuEaqqiry"(first character is a space).
I delete the space character, then it worked.