# after make or change password User dont login in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

after make or edit password User i have login error 'Incorrect username or password' in Yii2

login with user 'admin' is work ( i make admin user with actionCreate1)

```
auth_key: kYm0pvYAXY4IzuV7eYgGgtjSqoxxMNUL
password: $2y$13$QqsbMW3ErXwWOPad3abDYOPzh5XLwuEvQKBhZGEEDoT0Av5l0bE2S
```

but i make user or edit password , in login page i have error: 'Incorrect username or password'

**i think problem from beforeSave in Model USER**

User Table:

```
id                  int          
auth_key            text          
username            text           
password            text
```

actionCreate: **it's not work**

```
    public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new User();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

                if($model->save())
{
$model->img = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img');

                if($model->img !== null) $model->upload('img',$model->id);
                $model->save();
}
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
```

actionCreate1: **it's GOOD WORK**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->username = Yii::$app->request->post('User')['username'];
            $model->password = Yii::$app->request->post('User')['password'];
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Model User:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if($this->password) {
        $this->setPassword($this->password);
    }

    if($insert)
    {
        $this->generateAuthKey();
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}

public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}

public function generateAuthKey() {
    $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}

/**
 * @param $password
 * @return bool
 */
public function validatePassword($password) {
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne([
        'id' => $id
    ]);
}

public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {}

/**
 * @param $username
 * @return null|static
 */
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    return static::findOne([
        'username' => $username,
    ]);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->auth_key === $authKey;
}
```

Comment: In actionCreate you are saving model twice, why? Also you are not checking result of the second save. In actionCreate1 you are not checking result of save and you are manually assigning attributes which is done automatically by load method. This is bad coding.

Comment: in actionCreate i need record ID after insert. how to fix this problem? in actionCreate1 make user without problem and good login.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name for attribute storing password hash and raw password.

Either change password hash attribute to something like `passwod_hash` or raw password attribute to something like `raw_password` and modify the code accordingly to handle it.

Comment: so why i login with pass: 12345 user: admin , please check image: http://i.imgur.com/Xy78066.jpg

Comment: Show your `User` and `LoginForm` `rules()` methods.

Comment: user: public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['auth_key', 'username', 'password', 'role', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'mahal_tavalod', 'mahal_sodor', 'name_pedar', 'tarikh_tavalod', 'telephon', 'mobile', 'address', 'code_posti', 'sherkat_bime', 'shomare_gharardad'], 'string'],
            [[ 'code', 'created_at', 'status', 'codemeli', 'shomare_shenasname', 'sex', 'darsad_porsant', 'total_sod'], 'integer'],
            [['username','code','codemeli'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

Comment: LoginForm: public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

Comment: I'm not sure what is really wrong there. For LoginForm check if `$this->getUser();` returns User object. As for the User model - you are not checking if `$model->save()` returned true which is wrong.

Comment: sorry: please check image http://i.imgur.com/VipVyux.jpg .  i have error in change password

Comment: if i insert auth_key and pass VALUE for user admin on other users , other users login with pass 12345

Comment: I told you to rename the attribute - when you fetch existing User object its `password` is set to previously hashed raw password - I don't know what you do with it exactly but I guess you just pass it as it is during update when you don't want to change it - but in fact you are changing it to be something like "2y$13$Qqs..." instead of "12345".

Comment: please check again, work in actionCreate1 but dont work in actionCreate

Answer (score 0):

for fix this problem.

step1:
change before save Model USER

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if($insert)
        {
            if($this->password) {
                $this->setPassword($this->password);
            }

            $this->generateAuthKey();
        }

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
```

step2:
small change in update user

```
    In the first code
    $password = $model->password;

    if(Yii::$app->request->post('User')['password'] != null) {
$model->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash(Yii::$app->request->post('User')['password']);
}
else
{
 $model->password = $password;
}
```