# Yii2 displays error: Hash is invalid

Tags: php, yii2

I have an error in yii2 project. When I want to authenticate, **hash is invalid** error displays and authentication is not happening.
I store passwords in DB like this:

```
$newPassword->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($passwordModel->password);
```

And when the application runs at this line - the error happens:

```
public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }
```

My password field in the DB is type TEXT, so this is not a size issue.

Comment: can you verify if none of the two parameters passed to the `validatePassword()`  is null?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210391/yii2-validate-password-hash-is-invalid-error